# Should I write "focus" or "focuses" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The topic of telepathy is not very suitable for a science class, which focus(es)
>   should consist of empirical knowledge and established facts.

I'm not sure if I should write *focus* because I'm talking about *a* class, or write *focuses* because I'm talking about *empirical knowledge and established facts*.

Comment: Your original text no primary verb. The relative ***which-*** clause is syntactic gibberish, but it's not clear to me exactly what you *want* it to say. Perhaps *... **the focus of which** should consist of [blah blah]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers has a spot on explanation :)

Comment: @parkgatedev: After thinking more carefully, I have to admit there *can* be constructions where something like the syntax of OP's relative clause could be "valid". *Talking about quantum mechanics is not very suitable for first dates, which contexts should consist of social pleasantries and personal introductions*. Perhaps some people would say that's actually "invalid" (it's certainly "clunky"), but it's credible enough to me. and I'm sure with a little more ingenuity one could shoehorn the plural noun ***focuses*** into a similar utterance, instead of ***contexts***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The topic of telepathy is not very suitable for a science class whose
>   focus ought to be on empirical knowledge and established facts.

sounds (to me) better..

Answer (score 1):

> The topic of telepathy is not very suitable for a science class, which focus(es)
>   should consist of empirical knowledge and established facts.

The idea of *[focus](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/learner/focus)* is to concentrate on some single thing. Therefore I would use *focus* even though the "single thing" that you want to concentrate on has more than one component.

Or, if you wanted to get tricky, you could use *foci* and please the people who prefer Latin plural endings to English words. Additionally, *Foci* sounds better than *focuses* does, as a noun.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use *focus* or *focuses* in that sentence, because it has several other problems.

You can write something like:

*Telepathy is not a suitable topic for a science class, which should focus on ___ and ____.*

(By the way, many scientists would tell you that telepathy is a fine topic to discuss or investigate in a science class, and that science focuses on theories as well as "established facts".)

It is not normal to think of a focus "consisting of" something. It makes more sense to say that a focus *is* something.

The closest thing you could say to your original sentence that would be acceptable to at least some people might be something like

> The topic of telepathy is not very suitable for a science class, whose focuses should consist of empirical knowledge and established facts.

The following would be acceptable to more people:

> The topic of telepathy is not very suitable for a science class, whose focus should be limited to empirical knowledge and established facts.

It would be ok to use *focuses* instead of *focus.* It would also be also ok to use *foci* instead of *focuses.*

We can think of one focus being on more than one thing. We can also have more than one focus.